# What intensity range does img_as_ubyte use for converting 32-bit/16-bit images to 8-bit?

Tags: python, image-processing, bit, scikit-image

In Fiji, when converting a 32-bit or 16-bit image to 8-bit the displayed min and max intensity range is used for the conversion.

I have a z-stack image and was wondering what happens when I use img_as_ubyte in python to convert my stack to 8-bit.

Is a min and max intensity value chosen to linearly scale my stack? Would this min and max value correspond to a slice with the highest difference between min and max values?

I converted the 3 channels of my z-stack image from 16-bit to 8-bit using the following code in python:

```
skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean(ch1, (1, 2, 2),cval=0)
    
skimage.exposure.adjust_gamma(ch1_r,gamma=1,gain=2)
    
skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(ch1_r)
    
skimage.util.img_as_ubyte(ch1_r)
```

Does this method preserve the full intensity range of the slices in the stack?

Comment: The docs say “Negative input values will be clipped. Positive values are scaled between 0 and 255.” I think they mean that `max(img)` will be mapped to 255 and `min(img)` (after setting negative values to 0) will be mapped to 0.

Comment: But it is trivial to try it out with a small array of a few numbers to see what happens to them.